# Qual é o critério dos testes realizados na fila de análise?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Nos últimos dias tem aparecido vários testes (pegadinhas) na fila de análise e fiquei curioso em saber como funcionam esses testes.

Tem relação com a velocidade que levo para analisar e tomar uma decisão? Por exemplo, marcar para fechar duas perguntas em menos de 10 segundos.

Tem relação com as minhas ações? Por exemplo, a quantidade de perguntas que envio para serem analisadas diariamente?

Há algum post explicando o modo em que os testes são aplicados? Ou, há alguém que esteja familiarizado com este recurso para explicar como funciona?

Comment: Eles ocorrem aleatoriamente, com uma chance de 5% de aparecerem, pra cada fila